# How access the all the child of a object related to a model in django?

Tags: django

I'm not sure if my question makes sense, but here is what I'm trying to do:

I have Two Models:

```
class Task(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField()
    tasklist = models.ForeignKey('TaskList')
class TaskList(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField()
    users = models.ManyToManyField(User, related_name="lists")
```

How can I get all the tasks for a single User in one line?

Or is the code below the only solution?

```
user_tasks = []
user_tasklists = request.user.tasklists.all()
for list in user_tasklists:
    for task in list.task_set.all():
        user_tasks.append(task)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you have a user:

```
user = User.objects.get(pk=some_pk)

# Or if you need get the user from request:
# user = request.user

user_tasks = user.tasklist_set.all()
```

Now `user_tasks` is a queryset, so you can filter, or apply any queryset function.

To get Tasks (as shown in your last edit), you need query `Task` model:

```
Task.objects.filter(tasklist__users=user)
```

You can find the [related objects documentation here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/relations/)

Comment: Hi! Can you tell me where you get the attribute 'tasklist_set'? Also, where can I find the django documentation for this? Or the search term I should use to find the documentation?

Comment: As seen in the 2nd set of codes I posted above. The 'user' Im using is request.user

Comment: You use `_set` to access to reverse relationship. `request.user` is a also `User` object so there's no problem if you use it. I edited the answer with the documentation link.

Comment: Sorry for that. I might have misled you because of my question. I updated the question. Can you please check?

Comment: I think you should add a FK  `task` in `TaskList` model pointing to `Task` model

Comment: I have an FK from task pointing to TaskList. That's what I used in my solution(the 2nd set of codes).

Comment: If you need the tasks, you should query your Task model. `Task.objects.filter(tasklist__users=request.user)`

Comment: Oh! I didn't know I could do that. Thanks!

Comment: I edited the answer. Please, consider accept it for other people with a problem like this.